# Add demographic covariate in the LPA, but not as variables to cluster on using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, mclust

I'm doing LPA analysis on a dataset and wanted to add education, sex, and age to the LPA formula, but I don't want to use the variables for clustering. I'm using `mclust` package in R. I'm not sure how to approach.

```r
formula_lpa <- Indicators ~ AGE + SEX + EDUCATION

Mclust(data = data, modelNames = "VEE", G = 2,  formula = formula_lpa)
```